# How to use Android Compose Scaffold AppBar CollapsedScrollBehavior with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement the scaffold appBar collapsedScrollBehavior and it's working perfectly fine when the content is in compose like LazyColumn.

But in my use case, I am inflating the fragment with RecyclerView inside the Scaffold Content using [Android Compose Interop APIs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose). Scaffold appBar is not collapsing/expanding when I am scrolling the RecyclerView which is inside the fragment.

I know it's a unique scenario and could found any documentation under Android Compose Interop APIs. Kindly let me know if there is anything I can try to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible using `NestedScrollConnection`. You'll need to do two things:

1. Call `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollEnabled` in the root View you are inflating within `AndroidView`
2. Apply the `nestedScroll` modifier to the parent `Scaffold` and provide your `NestedScrollConnection`

You can read about this more in the documentation page [A parent composable containing a child AndroidView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/gestures#parent-compose-child-view).